# copy text in another file and append different strings shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

```
file=$2
isHeader=$true
while read -r line;
do
  if [ $isHeader ]
  then 
    sed "1i$line",\"BATCH_ID\"\n >> $file
  else
    sed "$line,1"\a >> $file
  fi
  isHeader=$false
done < $1

echo $file
```

In the first line I want to append a string and to the others lines I want to append the same string for the rest of the lines. I tried this but it doesn't work. I don't have any ideas, can somebody help me please?

Comment: what error do you get? could you show an example of what you want as an ouput from a simple input (3-4 lines)?

Comment: first line is a header, EX: "Name", "Date", "Number" and here i want to append a text to be a PK for EX: "ID", and to the others lines I want to append only a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear to me what you want to do, but if you simply want to append text at the end of each line, use ***`echo`*** in place of `sed`:

```
file=$2
isHeader=1
while read -r line;
do
  if [ $isHeader ]
  then
    #sed "1i$line",\"BATCH_ID\"\n >> $file
    echo "${line},\"BATCH_ID\"\n" > $file
  else
    #sed "$line,1"\a >> $file
    echo "${line},1\a" >> $file
  fi
  isHeader=0
done < $1

cat $file
```

Comment: Also changed the way you handled `$isHeader` "boolean"

Comment: for example? how can i change it?

Comment: I did change it: `isHeader=$true` `isHeader=$false` were wrong in your code, because they hadn't been initialized.  Have you tried the code I proposed? It seems to do what you expect.

Comment: i tried it and i made a few changes and everything works fine! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is slightly wrong because `echo`...`\a` produces a bell.  Also, **awk** or **sed** support regular expressions and are 10x faster at line-by-line processing.  Here it is in awk:

```
#! /bin/sh

script='NR == 1 { print $0 ",\"BATCH_ID\"" }
        NR  > 1 { print $0 ",1" }'

awk "$script" $1 > $2
```

In sed it's even simpler:

```
sed '1 s/$/,"BATCH_ID"/; 2,$ s/$/,1/' $1 > $2
```

To convince yourself of the speed, try this yourself:

```
$ time seq 100000 | while read f; do echo ${f}foo; done > /dev/null
real    0m2.068s
user    0m1.708s
sys     0m0.364s

$ time seq 100000 | sed 's/$/foo/' > /dev/null
real    0m0.166s
user    0m0.156s
sys     0m0.017s
```